# Reorder bars in ggplot2 stat_summary within group without faceting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
> df_long
      Goal  Incentive value
241    new       Land     1
865    new       Land     2
880    new       Land     2
943    new       Land     2
1267   new       Land     3
2854   new       Land     3
20271  new  Utilities     1
20286  new  Utilities     0
20910  new  Utilities     0
20973  new  Utilities     1
20988  new  Utilities     0
21297  new  Utilities     0
21312  new  Utilities     1
22884  new  Utilities     2
28856  new Permitting     3
28871  new Permitting     1
29495  new Permitting     1
29558  new Permitting     0
29573  new Permitting     3
29882  new Permitting     0
29897  new Permitting     1
31469  new Permitting     2
37441  ret       Land     1
37456  ret       Land     1
38080  ret       Land     1
38143  ret       Land     3
38158  ret       Land     3
38467  ret       Land     1
38482  ret       Land     1
40054  ret       Land     0
57486  ret  Utilities     0
58110  ret  Utilities     0
58188  ret  Utilities     0
58512  ret  Utilities     1
60099  ret  Utilities     2
66071  ret Permitting     3
66695  ret Permitting     1
66773  ret Permitting     1
67097  ret Permitting     1
68684  ret Permitting     0
```

I created a ggplot of mean `Incentive` by `Goal`using this code:

```
ggplot(df_long,aes(x=reorder(factor(Incentive), value), y=value, fill=Goal)) + 
    stat_summary(aes(width=0.7), fun.y="mean", geom="bar", position = "dodge") + 
    coord_flip()
```

And I got this result.
 [image]
Right now the `Incentives` are ordered in the graph by mean values, regardless of the `Goal`, which is what I want. However, how can I make the `new` bar to be above the `ret` bar for each `Incentive`? I.e. I dont want a list of all `new` followed a list of all `ret`, just change the order within each `Incentive`. I would also like to avoid faceting the graph, if possible.

This may seem like an easy task, but I've spent a while trying to accomplish it without success, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can specify `factor(Goal, levels = c("ret", "new")` and this should change the order of the columns.

Comment: this works beautifully, @kath, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by [kath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5892059/kath) addresses the problem. Below is the updated code and new graph with proper order.

```
ggplot(df_long,aes(x=reorder(factor(Incentive), value), y=value, 
                   fill=factor(Goal, levels = c("ret", "new")))) + 
        stat_summary(aes(width=0.7), fun.y="mean", geom="bar", position = "dodge") + 
        coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, set up the variable as an ordered factor before plotting as:

```
dflong$Goal = ordered(dflong$Goal, levels = c("ret", "new"))
```

This is still very similar to Kath's comment, but I find nice because it doesn't rename your legend title 'factor(Goal...' and saves you the step of renaming the legend title.